# I am having problem getting oracle vm working

Tags: oracle

I have tried everything from a multitude of web-sites. nothing works.
I have install dkms. I have tried to install virtualbox-dkms, but it is not found.
I tried signing the modules but mokutil will not load when I reboot the machine. I am not sure if I have my bois configured correct. I have no idea, what I am doing wrong here.
modprobe vboxdrv says :

```
 modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64
```

I get the error from /sbin/vboxconfig:

```
 Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxdrv.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxballoonctrl-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxautostart-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service.
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Please let me know what information you need and where I can start.
Thanks,
Donald

Comment: Couple of questions - have you tried turning off secure boot? Have you installed `build-essential`? (I think your main issue is secure boot)

Comment: Yes I have the package installed and I am sure I tried iwth the secure boot off, but I will try again right now. Report in a few min.

Comment: The only option I have in the bois is to turn it to other OS for secure boot. So I am not sure if it is off. But I am getting the same results. I did google this problem and they said if I chose this option on the bois it would be off. Thanks, donald

Comment: You have to either turn off secure boot or get the mokutil thing to work. Either one will do, but if you can't get one of those to work, virtualbox won't run.  mokutil was too much trouble for me so I turned off secure boot. It was a pain figuring out how to do it in the overly complicated ASUS UEFI system.

Comment: That is the system I have too. I am going to contact the manufactor and see if it is off or get mokutil to work. Thanks, Donald

Comment: My system is old so it may be different but on the Advanced Mode screen there was a entry Secure Boot. Clicking on that brought up a screen that showed Secure Boot State Enabled and a dropdown box " OS Type" that started at Windows UEFI.  I changed that to Other OS. Now when I boot I get a quick screen that says BOOTING IN INSECURE MODE so I know it worked.  If you don't get that BOOTING IN INSECURE MODE, it's still on.